# task_struct access in python

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to write python script to get information of task_struct(child_process, memory(mm_struct)). I don't think I can access task_struct in userspace, correct me if I am wrong.

One of the way is to create system call that return me task_struct information and access that information from c program. I know it is not recommended to create system call. But it's school project.

Is there any other efficient way like alternative system call, .. that can give me information about all child information, memory information about any particular process ?

Let me know if the requirement is not clear. Excuse me for my english

Comment: @iharob If i understand your question properly then you are asking me to use C instead of python. I need good GUI, so c is not a good option.

Comment: Don't say that... you can do good GUI with c, for example with gtk, how do you think python gui's are implemented? in c!, and that's precisely why I'm asking, because if you can do it in c, then it's doable in pyhton.

Comment: @iharob I have never done any GUI stuff in C. Yes, I can consider that as option if there is an easy way.

Comment: It's very easy, just write the c function and then google about creating c extensions for python. You will find simple examples implementing one function, change that function to yours, and that's it.

Comment: What does `task_struct` give anyway?

Comment: @iharob I don't think we can access task_struct from simple c program. My real question is how to access task_stuct ? task_struct contain all the information about particular process. Each process has it's own task_struct

Comment: Have you searched about the `/proc` filesystem? what information are you looking for? I think I can help you with that, and probably it's not accessible from userspace, but you can access that information for sure, think for example about `top` or `ps`.

Comment: @iharob we are not allowed to use proc, top or ps. It's school project and we forced to use some alternative techniques, basically to learn.

Comment: Oh, no... I wouldn't recommend an external program... never. I just mention that those programs have access to that information.